# Creation of jobs in Task Scheduler - C#

Tags: c#

I am creating a job upload program in c#. I have all the job information maintained in the config file.

When I create a job, I do pass an unique argument for that job.

```
using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
{
   TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
   TimeTrigger trigger = new TimeTrigger();
   var startTime = TimeSpan.Parse(section1["ScheduledTime"]);
                            trigger.StartBoundary = DateTime.Today + startTime;
   trigger.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
   trigger.StartBoundary = DateTime.Now;
   trigger.Id = "XXX";
   trigger.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
   td.Triggers.Add(trigger);
   td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(@"C:/JobUpload.exe", argument, ""));
   var foldername = ts.GetFolder(@"\Data");
   foldername.RegisterTaskDefinition(section1["JobName"], td);
 }
```

In the program, I have to check whether the job has any arguments. If no arguments are present (this occurs when the exe file is triggered manually), then I have to trigger the method A.

On the other hand, if the exe file is triggered through the job in task scheduler, then it has arguments associated with it, so I have to trigger the method B.

I am not sure on how to check whether a job has any arguments in C#.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

```
if (args.Length > 0)
{
  Console.WriteLine("more than 1");
  Logger.Info("More than 1");
  Debug.WriteLine("More than 1");
}
```

Comment: What development platform you are using? WPF? Forms?

Comment: I am just using a console application.

Comment: Did you check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791969/c-sharp-check-if-you-have-passed-arguments-or-not)? Your question is related to arguments to console application whereas all the content and the title is related to task scheduling, totally irrelevant.  Read this: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# Console Application Entry Point is the Main Method.

```
static int Main(string[] args)
```

as you can see there's a parameter to that Method, which is the arguments that's passed to your application.

You can access them as any normal array.

```
if(args[0] == "X")
   MethodOne();
else
   MethodTwo();
```

Comment: This works when I run the program through command line. But when the .exe file gets triggered, I am providing the argument name through "Add arguments (optional)" in Task scheduler. But that does not get captured in args[0]. Not sure where it gets captured.

Comment: When using Task Scheduler, args.Length == 0? Log the output to check for it.

Comment: I am new to C#, I have edited the code in the question. But it does not print anything when i manually run the job from task scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

In your console application, there should be an Program.cs with a `static void Main(string[] args)` method.

Any arguments given through command line would be passed in to the args parameter. If no arguments are passed in, the args.Length would be 0.

See [Command-Line Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb20e19t.aspx)